# Upload a variable to sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

In my app I want to fetch JSON data from a server. For that I want the user to enter a variable that goes into the fetching query, but the way I tried it my app doesn't get any response from the server:

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if(isset($_POST['name'])){
 $query = "INSERT INTO TestTable (name) VALUES ('$_POST[name]')";

 if(mysqli_query($conn,$query)){ 
     echo 'Data Submit Successfully';
 }else{
     echo 'Try Again';
 }    
}


$var = $_POST['name'];

 $query = "SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE id = '$var'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $array[] = $row;
    }


    header('Content-Type:Application/json');
    echo json_encode($array);
    mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

The uploaded variable is posted into the table as it should do. And If I set `$var` to a fixed value I do get a correct response. But what do I have to change so that my posted Variable gets into the selecting query?

Edit: here is the code of my uploading the variable and fetching the result - the `GetData()` and the `InsertData()` methods are used to upload and the other two to fetch:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<GetDataAdapter> GetDataAdapter1;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewlayoutManager;
    RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewadapter;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    String ServerURL = "https://x.com/test.php";
    EditText name;
    Button button;
    String TempName;
    String JSON_ID = "id";
    String JSON_NAME = "name";

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest;
    com.android.volley.RequestQueue requestQueue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GetDataAdapter1 = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView1);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerViewlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewlayoutManager);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                GetData();
                InsertData(TempName);
                JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL();
            }
        });
    }

    public void GetData() {
        TempName = name.getText().toString();
    }

    public void InsertData(final String a) {

        class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                String NameHolder = a;

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", NameHolder));

                try {
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(ServerURL);
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();


                    String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
                    Log.v("TAG 2", "Response: " +  responseStr);



                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
                return "Data Inserted Successfully";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                super.onPostExecute(result);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Submit Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }

        SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();

        sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(a);
    }

    public void JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL() {

        jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(ServerURL,

                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

    }

    public void JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(JSONArray array) {

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

            GetDataAdapter GetDataAdapter2 = new GetDataAdapter();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);
                GetDataAdapter2.setId(json.getInt(JSON_ID));
                GetDataAdapter2.setName(json.getString(JSON_NAME));

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            GetDataAdapter1.add(GetDataAdapter2);
        }

        recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(GetDataAdapter1, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to `var_dump($query)` and you should get a hint when you see the string :-)

Comment: You append the query string so instead of '$var' you do $query = "SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE name =".var;

Comment: Your SELECT query is open to sql injection. Either use mysqli_real_escape_string, or better learn about prepared statements

Comment: @thefolenangel I get a syntax error for it, are you sure you mean it like that?

Comment: You should consider creating a log file on the PHP side so you can write debug messages there. Here is a simple PHP logger you can use. https://gist.github.com/ryantxr/fb2b2fa9fa63b34a1bd9

Comment: put also the second part (the select part) inside the isset. You are getting an error if you run the select when nothing is posted.

Comment: @LelioFaieta I tried it, but even when I give `$var` a fix value I don't get an output anymore

Comment: you don't if you don't post anything to the page. Btw is your insert working properly?

Comment: The value I enter is posted to the table, if you mean that

Comment: You are susceptible to SQL injection hack attacks.  Please take a look at http://bobby-tables.com to learn about what SQL injection is and how to do SQL queries safely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest defining your post variable

```
$postVar = $_POST['variable'];
```

Then you should probably sanitise it before putting it in your SQL string.

I would prefer to use Prepared Statements.
You should read about them here https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp and use them instead as it fits your case exactly

Edit: How did you determine that your SELECT query didn't execute?

Edit 2:
So I tested out modified version of your code:

```
if(isset($_GET['name'])){
   $query = "INSERT INTO TestTable (name) VALUES ('$_GET[name]')";
   echo $query;
   echo "</br></br>";
}

$var = "$_GET[name]";
echo $var;
echo "</br></br>";

$query = "SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE name = '$var'";
echo $query;
```

The output that this produced by going to `fileName.php?name=getVariableCorrectlyPopulated` is:

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (name) VALUES ('getVariableCorrectlyPopulated')

getVariableCorrectlyPopulated

SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE name = 'getVariableCorrectlyPopulated'
```

As you can see that is with GET instead of POST but data is going in correctly, I suggest you do the same or similar when you first make your scripts.You can use XAMPP (for example) for Apache distribution and run your scripts locally.

Edit 3+4:

Tested and is working:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "test";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $array=array();
    $postVar =  $_POST['name'];
    //DONT FORGET TO SANITIZE

    $query1 = "INSERT INTO TestTable (name) VALUES ('$postVar')";
    if(mysqli_query($conn,$query1, false)){
//        echo 'Data Submit Successfully';
    }else{
        echo 'Try Again';
    }

    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE name = '$postVar'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $array[] = $row['name'];
    }

    echo json_encode($array);
}
?>
```

Please keep in mind there are way better ways to do this... See Prepared Statements above

Edit 5:
You should change your code to what I gave you in Edit 3+4 (and sanitise the post data as well) and edit your android code so that you handle the response from`doInBackground` method https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.

Comment: Edited my answer. Will delete my comments here, they are getting too many, maybe you should too.

Comment: Sorry, I still have the same problem as before. The value is entered into the table but I don't get it returned properly. Even when I use a fix value it doesn't return anything

Comment: Do you have any other suggestion maybe?

Comment: I had a type in my `$query2 = "SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE name = '$postVar'"` I had `id` instead of `name`, try it now

Comment: typo* , so I edited my answer again, that last code snippet works as I created a db to and tested it, prints is also working. Try copy pasting this with your db connection details.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong, but I still don't get the corresponding data returned..
Would you try my code as well, if I added it?

Comment: Sure if you can paste your code I could trace the exact error.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I added it. Do you want to test it? THen I provide the Adapters and layout as well?

Comment: The problem is not your php. Your `doInBackground` method in Android part never returns the results from the post request (nor you do anything with it). Something like `return EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);` at the end of your try block is needed.

Comment: When you post something in Android, picture it like if you submit a form. `doInBackground` is where you "populate" that form (your request). This method also hits the "Submit" button of that "form". After that it has to read what the page "answered" (in your case what was printed back) and return this (say as a String). After that the string you just returned is passed to another method `onPostExecute(Result)`. There you should do whatever you want to do with with start result (maybe you put it as text of a TextView ?). Read this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Comment: But why does it work then when I have a fixed value to select from the table and not when the value it is uploaded? Isn't it handled then as it is working?

Comment: Because your php, the select part is out of your if. So your `JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL` goes to the url WITHOUT posting anything. Your flow is like this: You post to serverurl (`doInBackground` method) --> Server inserts value and selects the value and prints it (but you never read it back in the app) --> now `JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL` method goes to the server url (brand new request, NO post data) --> the server doesn't insert again, only executes the select part (as it is out of the if) but as you didn't POST anything it does `SELECT..... WHERE name=' '` which returns nothing .

Comment: Ah okay, that sounds understandable for me. So is it like the script needs to be updated before the second part comes? Or why isn't the variable just valid for the whole script?

Comment: The script is executed for every "visit" of the page. Imagine your app like a browser - it goes to the url in tab 1 (`doInBackground` method) and posts data when it goes there so the script goes in the IF part. Then your app opens a 2nd "browser tab" and goes to the url again but this time posts nothing. So the variables are empty. The script is run once exactly at the moment you visit the page. Variables and everything resets when you reload the page. If we both go to the url you will not see what I have posted to it nor will I see what you posted etc etc...

Comment: I like your explanations, I have one more question: how would I let tab2 know then if tab 1 posted something and why would it be helpful? I mean tab two might know what was posted by tab 1 but how would it modify the php file with that information? Also in regards of my problem, how does the program handle it when it knows what's returned? It wouldn't change the php file, would it?

Comment: I mean if I read the result back from the inserting of the variable, how does the get method profit from it? It doesn't insert the variable back again or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: The two "tabs" should not know about each other. You should return what you get from `doInBackground` , and implement `onPostExecute(Result)` method, this is where what you returned from `doInBackground` goes to (the result parameter is what you return from `doInBackground`). In this method when you have the result parameter you can do whatever you want with it - stick it in TextView or whatever your plan is. This way when you post in `doInBackground` method, the select part will run properly, print the results in php, the Android picks them up as response, and returns it to `onPostExecute`.

Comment: But my post and get method don't know about each other, do they? They don't have an effect on each other, or not? I added a line to my `doInBackground()` method where I return the response. But what do I have to do then, to make the get methods fetch the data with the posted parameter? And is it even important to return the response in order to get the result from the get method that is following afterwards?

Comment: Ahh I think now I'm getting closer: the response of the inserting part already contains the information I want to have in the get part?

Comment: The response in `doInBackground` will have the `echo json_encode($array);` yes

Comment: Thank you very much, with your help I was able to solve it correctly!